# Simple use of Netty with RestEasy

Tags: java, rest, netty, resteasy

I am completely new to RestEasy and Netty.
I just want to run a very simple test to see how netty actually works. So I am using this code:

```
ResteasyDeployment deployment = new ResteasyDeployment();
deployment.setResourceClasses(Collections.singletonList(OAIProviderImpl.class.getName()));


        NettyJaxrsServer netty = new NettyJaxrsServer();
        netty.setDeployment(deployment);
        netty.setPort(TestPortProvider.getPort());
        netty.setRootResourcePath("");
        netty.setSecurityDomain(null);
        netty.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        netty.stop();
```

in a `Main()` method. `OAIProviderImpl.class` is just a class that implements a REST interface.
When I run this code. I get a `NullpointerException` on `netty.stop()` and by furthur going inside the `stop()` method, I can see that the exception is coming from `releaseExternalResources`.
The code above is copied from [Netty Reasteasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d0e2690)

Has anyone used this code without any problem? Can someone guide me please? Thanks.
UPDATE: here is the stack-trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.netty.NettyJaxrsServer.stop(NettyJaxrsServer.java:145)
    at nl.gridline.oai.NettyServerTest.test(NettyServerTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)


at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: @NormanMaurer: I posted the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the NettyJaxrsServer in the start method creates a private bootstrap object that is never saved globally.  So when you hit the stop method the global bootstrap reference is null.  Weird miss.

Comment: Created RESTEASY-794 - NullPointer netty stop, until then I just extend and override the start method.